# Android UIAutomator generated no JAR

Tags: android, testing, ui-automation

I try to build the jar to use uiautomator from Android.

I create a very simple test as follow:

```
public class TestUIAutomator extends UiAutomatorTestCase  {

public TestUIAutomator(String name) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    // Simulate a short press on the HOME button.
    getUiDevice().pressHome();
    //super(name);
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}
```

}

Then I use ant to create uitest project with following command:

```
android create uitest-project -n HelloWorldTestUIAutomator -t 11 -p D:\tec_met_android\HelloWorldTestUIAutomator
```

Then I run build.xml from Eclipse and I get the following message in console :

```
 Buildfile: D:\tec_met_android\HelloWorldTestUIAutomator\build.xml
 [echo] Out file : D:\tec_met_android\HelloWorldTestUIAutomator\bin/HelloWorldTestUIAutomator.jar
 [echo] Android Ant Build. Available targets:
 [echo]    help:      Displays this help.
 [echo]    clean:     Removes output files created by other targets.
 [echo]    build:     Builds the test library.
 [echo]    install:   Installs the library on a connected device or
 [echo]               emulator.
 [echo]    test:      Runs the tests.
 [echo] It is possible to mix targets. For instance:
 [echo]    ant build install test
 [echo] This will build, install and run the test in a single command.
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 Total time: 414 milliseconds
```

It shown successful. **But there is no JAR in the output directory.**

Thank for help..!

Comment: Are you using eclipse for coding?